# Is there a change log subscription for Telegram Bot API?

Tags: subscription, telegram-bot, changelog

I want to get Telegram Bot API changes in my email inbox instead of checking its website. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution here is to code your custom script that scrapes the [documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and provides you updates.

Join also the [@BotNews](https://telegram.me/BotNews) official channel for updates.